# UI router nested views issue

Tags: angular-ui-router

I'm struggling once again with ui router.

I'm trying some nested views.

The main layout home.html is called when navigating to url/account/management/Company (route managed by Symfony). Then I want ui router to kick in.

looks like this:

```
<div ui-view="discrimSelector"></div>
<div ui-view="main"></div>
```

Then this is my js routing definition:

```
FlatView.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("");

    $stateProvider
      .state('flatView', {
          url:"",
          views: {
              'main': {
                  controller:"flatViewHome",
                  templateUrl:Routing.generate('_NRtworks_FlatView_elementList') 
              },
              'discrimSelector@flatView': {
                  templateUrl:Routing.generate('_NRtworks_FlatView_DiscrimSelector')                 
              }
          }
      });

});
```

I've followed advices to use full names for the second view but it doesn't get loaded (the "main" template gets loaded great and I can see in the net tab that the file of the other template is actually fetched but not plugged into the ui-view).

what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `@flatView` from `discrimSelector@flatView`.

The notation is uiview@state. You should use it only when you want to load another state's ui-view.

E.g. Imagine you had two nested states. When you are in the child state you want to load the parent's (any ancestor) ui-view then you would use this notation.

```
 $stateProvider
  .state('parent', {
      views: {
          'A': {
              ...              
           },
          'B': {
              ...           
          }
      }
  })

 .state('child', {
       views: {
          'C': {
              ...              
           },
          'A@parent': {
              ...           
          }
      }
  });
```